# 4 memory modules of the same kind not working?

Tags: memory, motherboard, hardware-failure, boot

I am trying to install 2 extra pairs of 2GB on my server, the motherboard is a GA-EP41-UD3L which is said to support up to 8GB and has 4 memory slots.

I have 4 memories of 2 GB being all of it:

- DDR2
- 1.80V
- 5-5-5-18
- 800MHz
- Model: CM2X2048-6400C5

Once I plug it all, the board does 4 short beeps which entitles power failure by the manual information.

If I plug 2 of them at slots 1 and 3 it works just fine and detects 4GB, if I plug 3 of them on slots 1, 2 and 3 it boots up but does not detect the memory at slot 2.

Have also tried to set the bios to default before booting in.

- What am I possible doing wrong here ?
- Is this a motherboard problem ?
- Memory problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the memory modules [single-sided](http://www.computing.net/answers/hardware/double-vs-single-sided-ram-/67771.html)?

> Because of Intel chipset limitation, please use single-side memory
>   module if four memory modules are to be installed.

From the Gigabyte support site (same info for both versions) [here](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3454#sp)

Comment: Tog what exactly would be single side ? All I know is that there are 4 slots and 4 equal memories.

Comment: The difference between dual and single sided is to do with how it is accessed on the module (not to be confused with dual channel). I can't find info on your memory on the Corsair site. Try sending their tech guys an email asking which type of memory you have

Comment: You may get away with boosting the voltage a little (try 1.9V first). If that doesn't work, try increasing the latencies a bit too. If your BIOS allows it, make sure to set the active-to-CMD latency (sometimes just called 'CMD' or 'command rate') to 2. Usually you can push one limit a little if you ease off a bit on the others. Make sure to test the configuration thoroughly with [memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org) before booting any OS installation you care about.

Comment: Tog thx will try to search about it and if I can't find anything mail them. David I would wish not to go out of the stock.