# 4 identical memory modules not working

Tags: memory, motherboard

My Asus P5G41-M SI motherboard supports 8gb of RAM. I have 4 x 2GB identical modules (DDR2 800MHz PC2-6400 240 PIN DIMM) which I bought [here](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B00I5MZVQI/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o09_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1). I can put any pair in and it boots with 4gb but if I add the other pair, it won't boot. (The fan spins but I don't get the boot screen). It also boots with a pair in either the black or yellow slots (just not both), so the slots seam fine,

It's the identical problem posted [here](https://superuser.com/questions/364056/4-memory-modules-of-the-same-kind-not-working) where it looks like the system requires single-sided RAM. My motherboard doesn't list this limitation in its [manual](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6uYetlTWMPNYkMydXp6RXJJZVE/view?usp=sharing), though the manual has the wiggle clause "Specifications are subject to change without notice", so maybe there's a limitation? I've tried everything I can think of and am at wits end, so any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: There is such term as rank, motherboard may accept maximum allowed by manufacturer total ranks, so if your RAM has 2xRank then total rank may exceed motherboard's maximum

Comment: Thanks Alex. Is rank the same as "sided"? So 1x rank is "single-sided" and 2x rank is "double-sided"? I just checked the manual and the 4 x 2gb configurations it lists are only for single-sided dimms.

Comment: No, sticks could be single sided , but internal structure will make them double ranked. To simplify meaning of rank, - think about it as 1 rank - it is one RAM module, when it is 2xRank then manufacturer place 2 modules on a single stick that's why motherboard see such modules as doubled

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on sided vs. ranked. Are double-sided dimms _typically_ 2xRank? My dimms are double sided with 8 chips per side (16 total), so _probably_ 2xRank?

Comment: I saw double-sided with 1xRank, it all depend what type of memory chips manufacturer used. Put exact number from label on your mem.stick on google with extra keyword "specification", the is a huge chance you will find datasheet for your particular RAM