# How to determine maximum total rank for a motherboard (Asus P5G41-M SI)

Tags: memory, motherboard

I'm trying to max out my motherboard's memory by installing 4 x 2GB identical memory sticks. It works fine with two sticks, but won't post when I add the other two. (I tried swapping the sticks around to ensure one wasn't bad and they all seem fine).

The sticks are dual rank and when I posted a question about it [here on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1175374/4-identical-memory-modules-not-working) it was suggested that I may be surpassing the motherboards total rank capacity. I read through the user manual and don't see a mention of a maximum total rank. Is there a way to determine a motherboards total rank by inspection or through other specifications?

EDIT: From the manual, "Memory: Dual-channel memory architecture - 4 x 240-pin DIMM sockets support unbuffered non-ECC  DDR2 800/667MHz memory modules - Supports up to 8GB system memory." Here's the [manual](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6uYetlTWMPNWnVLM1VWUHl4S0E/view?usp=sharing).

It's looking like the Chipset is the limiting factor for the type of memory can be used. My MB using an Intel G41.

Comment: Seth, sorry, I should have provided more info. I added an edit, which includes the manual and the spec for the memory.

Comment: That's really helpful. From what I understand your machine is able to boot if you use either set of two sticks but not when you use all four at once. [This seems](http://serverfault.com/questions/69612/dimms-single-vs-double-vs-quad-rank) to be a good explanation in regards to rank. I don't really have an idea why it would behave this way.

Comment: Thanks for the links. It's not looking like rank is the issue. I talked to the local shop that installed the MB and they said I'm rolling dice with any modules other than a reputable brand (they use Kingston and Crucial). My no-name modules are dual rank and I went to Kingston's website and found a [module](http://www.kingston.com/dataSheets/KVR800D2N6_2G.pdf) that is certified for my MB and dual rank. I ordered the Crucial equivalent (found it at half the price) and will post back with results when it arrives.